# XML Parsing - how to get the Node name value

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a XML file in following format,

```
<zodiaco signo="Aries">
<prediccion tipo="texto">
Hoy te dispersas un poco...Solo tienes que concentrarte en tus problemas para poder solucionarlo. ¡No dejes que nada te desconcentre!
</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="amor">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="salud">5</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="trabajo">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="dinero">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="numero_suerte">32</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="pclave"/>
</zodiaco>
```

I want to get the value of "signo" of zodiaco node. please help me.

Comment: Try this Link:

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/android-xml-adventure-parsing-data-with-saxparser/

Answer (score 0):

```
private void parsePrediction(int ResId){
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory  factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); 
        parser.setInput(getResources().openRawResource(ResId), null);

        int parserEvent=parser.getEventType();
        String signo;
        while(parserEvent !=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (parserEvent) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                String tag = parser.getName();
                if (tag.compareTo("zodiaco") == 0) {
                    signo = (parser.getAttributeValue(null,"signo"));                   
                }
                break;
            }
            parserEvent=parser.next();  
        }

        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In ResId you put the resource id of the xml file. You can get the id with:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("the name of your file", "the dir where the file is", context.getPackageName());
```

Hope it works!